# What do nested object literals mean in grunt.js files?

Tags: javascript, build, gruntjs

I'm having trouble understanding nesting that sometimes shows up in `grunt.js` files. In the following example, what do nested objects like `concat.dist` and `min.dist` mean? Is the `dist` key referencing another named task or is it simply a configuration object? What exactly gets called when executing the `concat` and `min` tasks?

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    // …
    concat: {
      dist: {
        src: ["<banner:meta.banner>", "<file_strip_banner:lib/main.js>"],
        dest: "dist/main.js",
      }
    },
    min: {
      dist: {
        src: ["<banner:meta.banner>", "<config:concat.dist.dest>"],
        dest: "dist/main.min.js",
      }
    },
    // …
  });

  // …
  grunt.registerTask("default", "lint qunit concat min");
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In grunt, tasks that support this kind of nesting are called **[multi tasks](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/docs/api.md#gruntregistermultitask)**, and the nested objects are called **targets**. Suppose you have the following multi-task:

```
 concat: {
    dist: {
       src: ["<banner:meta.banner>", "<file_strip_banner:lib/main.js>"],
       dest: "dist/main.js",
    },
    dev: {
       (...)
    }
 }
```

This means you have the multi task **concat** with the targets **dist** and **dev** inside it. You can run all targets of any multi task by typing the name of the task on console. For example:

```
grunt concat
```

will run both concat and dev. On the other hand, you can also specify which target to run explicitly:

```
grunt concat:dist
```

will only execute the **dist** target.

As far as I know, if you have two multitasks with targets of the same name (like your example *min.dist* and *concat.dist*), this doesn't mean that both **dist** are somehow referencing the same thing, they just happen to share the same name.

Comment: I believe what you're referring to as "targets" are called subtasks in gruntjs. here is an multitask that uses `dist` and `dev` as example subtasks

Comment: In Grunt's doc on github they use the term target: "You can run all targets of any multi task by just specifying the name of the task. In this case, running grunt lint would automatically run the all target..."

Comment: Interesting, it looks like "target" is what they are officially documenting, but subtask is also used a lot in descriptions and examples as well - especially on task repos (SO removed the link I provided). Do you know if there is intended to be a distinguishment between the two terms? or was subtask the "old term" for describing targets? just curious at this point, especially given that new grunt users might be confused by it.

Comment: Grunt officially sticks to the term 'target'. There are some extensions that use the term 'subtask' but mean the same thing. I think I even saw one project that simply referred to them as 'multi-task sub-properties'. I would say 'target' should be used, but it is good to be aware of the others as well.

Comment: "`grunt concat` will run both concat and dev" should say "[...] will run both _dist_ and dev", maybe you can edit that @alemangui (since my edit wasn't accepted). Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Like the answer states, those or "multi targets" .. I did a vid on multi tasks [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRWhjOxG7EE)